# Google Map MarkerClusterer style

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Im using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer for large amounts of markers using this code:

```
// create map               
var map = new google.maps.Map($el[0], args);
// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];
markers = map.markers;
var markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({map, markers});
```

And its working fine.
But i need to change style for the Marker Clusterer or better use an svg.
Cant find any example online.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify custom cluster marker for a Google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71129102/how-to-specify-custom-cluster-marker-for-a-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this:

```js
var renderer = {
            render: ({ count, position }) =>
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    
                    label: {text: String(count), color: "white", fontSize: "12px"},
                    position,
                    icon: "/_assets/img/marker.svg",
                    // adjust zIndex to be above other markers
                    zIndex: Number(google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX) + count,
                }),
        };
        
        

        var markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({map, markers, renderer});
```

Comment: This contains deprecated code: `google.maps.Marker` since 21 Feb 2024.